# How to provide deep links to robo test

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I installed deep links to my application so that automatic login process will be performed.

I can upload apk and robo script, but how can I execute deep links.
I usually execute a deep link with the command like

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW "myapp://registration?countryCode=JP\&phoneNumber=09038491823\&verifyCode=123456\&password=acqoaoq123"
```

The document says that I can provide up to three deep links:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test#deep_links

However, I cannot figure out how to provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Firebase Console

If you start your test through the **Firebase Console**: At the **Select Dimensions** dialog (the dialog after you upload the APK), scroll all the way to the bottom and click **Advanced Options**. Some new option will appear below, one of them is **Deep links (optional)**.

[image: Deep links option]

#### gcloud

The **gcloud** command-line app currently does not support passing deep links (as of October 2019).

Comment: I found the option. However, I cannot use it to log in my app before the Robo start crawling.